# Downside to use a higher current Solid State Relay?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I need to buy a solid state relay and I found that the price difference between a 10A one and a 40A one is really small, sometimes even 0. So I'm wondering, what are the downsides of buying the bigger ones which is probably more robust if it's only a few cents more ?
I looked at the datasheet and from what I understand, the control circuit is the same, and the output voltage drop is also the same. So I'm wondering, with a price difference that small, the company making them would probably have benefited from only having one reference to build and sell, so if they're still making the small ones, there should be a reason, right ?

Comment: Post the datasheets of both.

Comment: https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/789378/ANV/SSR-25VA/1

Comment: Increased cost, size and leakage current spring to mind.

Comment: I didn't think about the leakage current, it's true that it might be a problem. The datasheet I have doesn't even mention it, I'll find a better one. About the size, it's exactly the same form factor and about the price, my question is beside that, for example let's say I can have a 10A and a 40A ssr for exactly the same price, is there any reason not to go with the 40A one